# How to require a module as a shorter reference in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Python, I can import a module and assign a shorter reference to it, like:

```
import long_library_name as l
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Ruby?

```
require 'long_library_name' as l
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.

Ruby's `require` doesn't work anything like Python or JavaScript, it's more analogous to C's `include`. All you're doing is loading the files provided by `long_library_name` into memory, whatever constant (or constants) those files expose are exposed globally using whatever name the library author chooses.

It is purely by convention that most gems named (for example) "foo_bar" expose a single top-level constant named `FooBar`. The same gem could expose a top-level constant named anything, or many constants named anything.

All of that said, you can assign the value of any existing constant to a new constant:

```
ARB = ActiveRecord::Base
```

But that is a very abnormal thing to do in Ruby, and it may break *lots* of things. Especially in Rails, it *will* break many things in weird ways, including hot code reloading.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough explanation!

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend it either, but I don’t thing it will _break_ anything. Code reloading is based on the original name which isn’t changed by assigning it to another constant (only the first constant matters). Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @Stefan This is indeed a problem, so much so that Zeitwork now blows up if you do this. The problem is the reference retained in `ARB` above never changes, even if `ActiveRecord::Base` is reloaded. This means you have a stale out-of-date version of your class in one variable, and a new potentially different one accessible  via `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: @Stefan `ActiveRecord::Base` is a bad example, I don't think it's autoloaded, but very simply, in any Rails app, try this in a `rails console`: `X = MyModel; reload! X == MyModel` and you'll find that `X` is no longer equal to `MyModel`. This creates all kinds of subtle problems in Rails, for example, an instance of `X` is no longer considered to be `is_a?(MyModel)`, meaning you cannot assign it to a `belongs_to :my_model`.  This is why Rails uses things like `class_name: 'MyModel'`, and not `class: MyModel`: It's dangerous to retain references to specific instances of classes.

Comment: Yes indeed, but those staleness problems apply to “regular” code, too. For example `foo = Foo.first ; reload! ; foo.class == Foo`.

Comment: @Stefan Not the same. `foo` is a local variable that doesn't persist across requests. `F` is a constant that may live forever across requests and code reloads.